# ESP32 CAM with Micropython, cannot get Pin.IN value to be anything but '1'

Tags: esp32, gpio, micropython

I'm trying to set up a PIR sensor with the ESP32-CAM. I'm using the firmware located here: [ESP CAM](https://github.com/lemariva/micropython-camera-driver). Firmware is based on Micropython 1.14 with the Thonny IDE on Mac. I can get the camera to work. My issue is trying to get this PIR sensor to work. I can only get the value of 1, even if I don't connect anything to the board. No amount of hand waving in front of the sensor seems to help. Not sure what else to do. Code is as follows:

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

pir = Pin(15, Pin.IN)
while True:
  print(pir.value())
  sleep(1)
```

I have also tried using Signal to invert it, however instead of only getting '1' I would get '0.' I have also tried Pins 4, 14, 13 and 12. The sensor works, I’ve gotten it to work on the same ESP board using arruino IDE. Dunno if it’s of any use, but I’ve gotten Pin.OUT to work with an LED using micropython, so the pins should be available to use. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try disconnecting the PIR sensor and wiring the pin it was connected to to ground. If you still read 1 you've got the wrong pin.

Comment: @romkey this did work when I connected it to the ground on the ESP and not the ground rail on the breadboard. I did have a power supply on the breadboard but the ESP doesn’t seem to accept GND from that. If I link the ESP ground to the rail, everything works. Thanks!